# Problemas con el envío de notificaciones de correo en Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, servidor

Estoy trabajando con laravel 5.6 y estoy teniendo dificultades con el envío de notificaciones de cambio de contraseña a los usuarios. Primero funcionaba sólo si estaba conectado desde el servidor local que se crea con `php artisan serve` pero cuando entraba desde otra pc con la dirección IP del servidor me lanzaba el siguiente error:

> "Connection could not be established with host smtp.unica.cu
>   [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido.  #0]"

Y ahora de pronto también me da el mismo error cuando estoy desde el servidor local. ¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba usar el siguiente comando para limpiar el cache:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

y luego reinicia tu servidor, espero te funcione.

Comment: Sip parese que tenia conflicto entre las dos direcciones que estaba usando, ya lo solucioné, gracias.